# NOT NULL constraint failed: pregunta_pregunta.created En la línea 1:

Tags: mysql, sql, django, sqlite, django-models

Me devuelve error: NOT NULL constraint failed: pregunta_pregunta.preguntaTest
¿Qué sucede?

Sentencia SQL

```
INSERT INTO `pregunta_pregunta` (`numeroPregunta`, `modalidadPregunta`, `preguntaTest`, `respuestaLetra`, `aRespuesta`, `bRespuesta`, `cRespuesta`, `dRespuesta`, `eRespuesta`) VALUES
(1, 'administrativo','La instalación en soporte es:', 'A', 'Es obligatoria.', 'Depende de la capacidad técnica.', 'Es voluntaria.', 'Requiere un previo convenio.', '');
```

Error al ejecutar SQL en volcado de datos a SQLite:

```
Resultado: NOT NULL constraint failed: pregunta_pregunta.created
En la línea 1:
INSERT INTO `pregunta_pregunta` (`numeroPregunta`, `modalidadPregunta`, `preguntaTest`, `respuestaLetra`, `aRespuesta`, `bRespuesta`, `cRespuesta`, `dRespuesta`, `eRespuesta`) VALUES
        (1, 'administrativo','La instalación en soporte es:', 'A', 'Es obligatoria.', 'Depende de la capacidad técnica.', 'Es voluntaria.', 'Requiere un previo convenio.', '');
```

Clase:

```
class Pregunta(models.Model):
    preguntaTest = models.TextField()
    modalidadPregunta = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=[
    ('administrativo', 'administrativo'),])
    numeroPregunta = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    respuestaLetra = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=[
    ('A', 'A'),('B', 'B'),('C', 'C'),('D', 'D'),],null=True, blank=True)
    aRespuesta = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    cRespuesta = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    dRespuesta = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    eRespuesta = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    bRespuesta = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: En esta consulta `INSERT INTO pregunta_pregunta (numeroPregunta, modalidadPregunta) VALUES
(1, 'administrativo')` insertas valores **solamente para dos columnas**. Las otras columnas en ese caso asumirían un valor `NULL` por defecto, pero una o más de esas columnas (que no se mencionan en la consulta) tiene una restricción `NOT NULL`, o sea, no admite valores nulos, para todas las columnas que tienen esa restricción debes indicar siempre un valor, o en la definición de la tabla poner un valor por defecto.

Comment: Por lo que veo falta una coma " , " luego del campo 'administrativo' que insertas, en la siguiente sentencia sql: 
INSERT INTO `pregunta_pregunta` (`numeroPregunta`, `modalidadPregunta`, `preguntaTest`, `respuestaLetra`, `aRespuesta`, `bRespuesta`, `cRespuesta`, `dRespuesta`, `eRespuesta`) VALUES
(1, 'administrativo', 'La instalación en soporte es:', 'A', 'Es obligatoria.', 'Depende de la capacidad técnica.', 'Es voluntaria.', 'Requiere un previo convenio.', '');

Comment: Ese error de la coma ha sido al colocar en stackoverflow. El error está relacionado con el tema NULL, pero no comprendo bien qué se pasa, ya que tengo indicado que permita null.

Comment: Tenes permitido eso en la db? como creaste esa tabla.. tu modelo no tiene nada que ver con la tabla..

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el `CREATE TABLE` de tu tabla? En línea de comandos puedes poner esto: `pragma table_info('pregunta_pregunta');` o bien ejecutar un comando SQL: `SELECT sql 
FROM sqlite_master 
WHERE name = 'pregunta_pregunta';`

Answer (score 0):

El error me lo daba la clase Pregunta, concretamente las columnas created y updated:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Corregido permitiendo NULL:

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True, blank=True)
```